# Qt - c++ : about how to use QFileInfo without object

Tags: c++, qt

I'm sorry if this was asked before but I couldn't get the right words in search and that might have effected the search results , anyways I returned to c++ and I decided to program a simple tool , while I was programming I needed a way to search for a file in Qt , this is the code:

```
void Main_Sorter::SearchForFile(QString Path , QString extention , QString FileName)
{

    QDirIterator dir(Path , QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

    while(dir.hasNext())
    {

        dir.next();
        if(QFileInfo(dir.filePath()).isFile())
            if(QFileInfo(dir.filePath()).suffix() == extention)
                if(QFileInfo(dir.filePath()).fileName() == FileName)
                    qDebug()<<"file found ! " + FileName;

    }

}
```

I was wondering how are we using the class name alone here ? " QFileInfo " without an object to control it ? and how did we get an QFileInfo object from

```
 QFileInfo(dir.filePath())
```

it's been too long since I used c++ but I don't remember using such things ?

Comment: You're not using it without an object. You couldn't :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access static class data you can use :: operator, like

```
QFileInfo::someStaticData
```

Moreover, by typing

```
if(QFileInfo(dir.filePath()).isFile())
```

you are creating temporary QFileInfo object, which is deleted right after the if statement.
What you would probably want is to save the object to some local variable, like:

```
QFileInfo fileInfo(dir.filePath());
```

and use that variable in if statements:

```
if(fileInfo.isFile()) {
    if(fileInfo.suffix() == extention)
    ....
}
```